# No mobile devices in Intune - Testing a few users from Hybrid SCCM to Intune Standalone

Tags: sccm-2012, mobile-devices, sccm-2012-r2, microsoft-intune, mdm

I'm testing at the moment with a few users to migratie from Hybrid SCCM to Intune Standalone. I followed this steps:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/mdm/deploy-use/migrate-hybridmdm-to-intunesa

I create also a group to migrate a few users for testing.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/mdm/deploy-use/migrate-mixed-authority

I see after this in intune that the Android Mobile device is by Intune.
And the mobile phone looks also good and the Company Portal too.
But I can only find the mobile device in the Azure AD. When I go to devices to manage the device I didn't see the device.

One time I create a new account and connect the mobile phone and it was showing up in Intune, I could also start a remote Teamviewer session to take over the mobile phone. But the next day this mobile was also gone.. And the status is now set on NONE. I didn't understand what's going wrong here.

Could someone explain me what I must do to let it work the right way?